# Different response structures for different "Success/2xx" response codes - Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

Does microservice artchitecture/ rest api standards allow for different structures for different response codes like, say, for 200 and 207 ?

If yes, how can I implement the same in my spring boot restful application ?

Comment: Do you mean that the same endpoint can return different 2xx response codes, or that You have different endpoints which return different 2xx codes? Big difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes, for example think about response code 200 vs. response code 404: with the first one a valid object will be returned, but for the second one - some error object should be returned. Completely different structures. About implementation, of course there are many ways, I'd recommend to take a look on [ResponseEntity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html).

Comment: My question talks about comparison between 200 and 207. Im aware about exception handling.

Comment: @user1354825 the idanz answer is all you need, itś up to your implementation to decidne when send 200, 204, 207. if you're looking for a transparent way to make springboot do that for you then there is none.

Comment: @Sombriks so you recommend using a Generic or a superclass type or say a String/Object as return type ?

Comment: @user1354825 I'd recommend to use the ResponseEntity class as described in the answer. Note that it is generic so you can return it with different types (T) for different response codes.

Comment: @idanz Good point, and I would even say that for a single response code of 200 OK, I would expect most endpoints in a useful application to return different structures

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that giving the proper error code(200/207 etc) will be under the purview of business logic. You can do the following:

1. `ResponseEntity<Object>` should be the return type of your controller method.
2. Return Spring ResponseEntity after manipulating as shown in the example. For the more common ones, spring has in-built methods(shown for 200 & 204). For custom error codes, Spring allows for manually creating the object with required params.

   ```
   @GetMapping(path = "/demo/example")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getData (
           @RequestParam(name = "auth_id") String authId
   ) {
   //Logic
   //200
   //return ResponseEntity.ok().body(objFor200Response);

   //204
   //return ResponseEntity.accepted().body(objFor204Response);

   //207
   //return new ResponseEntity<>(objFor207Response,HttpStatus.MULTI_STATUS);
   ```

   }

I hope this answers your query, happy coding :)